# My logistic function in js is formatted wrong, and I can't figure it out

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JS and I'm trying to write a function that adds a partial point to my participant's score, `acc`, based on the amount of time it has taken for them to answer the question, `test.trial_duration`. The trials last 15000ms before ending that trial with 0 points and moving onto the next one. The function I want to use is:

acc + (1 / (1 + 0.45^ (-x + 7500)))

So the code I wrote out is:

```
acc += (1/(1+Math.pow(0.45,(-test.trial_duration+7500))));
```

But there are no points added to my participant's score. I did trouble shooting and putting in simple, non-dynamic values works fine (e.g., `acc += (1/4)` so I'm pretty confident this is me not knowing how to properly format my logistic function. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have tried very hard to find the correct formatting and have not been successful.

Thank you!

EDIT: added the semi-colon, that was in the code originally I just left it out here on accident. Same issue; won't add to score.

Edit: I think the issue might be with raising the power to my variable. It works okay when I'm using the variable outside of the exponent (e.g., `acc += (1 / test.trial_duration)`). Any ideas as to why that might be?

Comment: acc += 1 / (1 + Math.pow(0.45, -(test.trial_duration - 7500)));